# Getting error message for static main

Tags: java, static, syntax-error, program-entry-point, public

this is the error message i receive in the cmd whenever i try to compile it... 
error: invalid method declaration; return type required
static main(String args[])

this is my code (the error appears at the last declaration).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

public class Counter extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final font FONT = new Font("Impact", Font.PLAIN, 72);
    private final File SOUND = new File("sound/tick.wav");

    private Timer timer;
    private int time;

    public Counter() {
        set0paque(false);
        setPrefferedSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        time = 60;
        timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints,KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setFont(FONT);
        g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        String text = "00:" +String.valueOf(time);
        int width = g.getFontMetrcis().stringWidth(text);
        g2.drawString(text, getWidth() / 2 - width / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        time--;

        if(time == 0) {
            shutdown();
        }
        repaint();
        playsound();

    }

    private void shutdown() {
        try{
            Runtime runtime =  Runtime.getRuntime();
            runtime.exec("shutdown -s -t 0");
            Systen.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static main(String args[]) {
        JWindow window = new JWindow();
        window.add(new Counter());
        window.pack();
        window.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thank you :

Comment: `public static main(String args[]) {` --> `public static void main(String args[]) {` You forgot the return type.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is: you have not specified a *return type* for your `main()` method.  Supposing that you want to be able to use the method as the entry point for an application, the return type you want is `void`.

Comment: Seems like with a little effort you could have figured this out yourself. It helps not to just panic when you see an error message but to stop look at it ***carefully*** and think about what it might be saying. You could also google for any example of another Java program with main, such as Google Java main method and then compare that example to your own code. Don't be lazy, careless or jump to conclusions. It will help you a lot to cultivate patience and focus and attention and an eye for details.

Answer (score 2):

Every method declaration must have a return type. If you don't want to return anything (as is the case with `main`), you should declare the return type as `void`:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Here --^
```

Comment: but then i get 19 new error messages :o